# Convert JSON to Avro in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, avro, apache-nifi-registry

I want to convert json data to avro.
I have used GenerateFlowFile and put dummy json value [{"firstname":"prathik","age":21},{"firstname":"arun","age":22}].
I have then used ConvertRecord processor and set JsonTreeReader and AvroRecordSetWriter with AvroSchemaRegistry which has the following schema:[AvroScehma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iulu.jpg)

But i am getting this as my output: [Output (Avro Data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsonb.jpg)

I am new to Apache Nifi.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Set you AvroRecordSetWriter  to Embed Avro Schema. Then you should be able to view the converted data (formatted)

Comment: Thanks for your input.

I have set the write strategy in AvroRecordSetWriter as Embedded Avro. And i have received the following output  :

Objavro.schema€{"type":"record","name":"person","namespace":"nifi","fields":[{"name":"firstname","type":"string"},{"name":"age","type":"int"}]}avro.codecnull¢ÈFB¡-Ž`0„Ûv‚L@prathik*arun,¢ÈFB¡-Ž`0„Ûv‚L@

Again  is red dot.

Comment: Which NiFi version are you using? Could you provide the configuration for the `JsonTreeReader` and `AvroRecordSetWriter`?

Answer (score 0):

> But i am getting this as my output: Output (Avro Data)

That's to be expected. Avro is a binary file format, and what you see is an attempt to make that data viewable in a text format. It's supposed to act like that.